# iOS: Key Window subview elements crashing from UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I am adding a subview over an app's key window, so that the subview covers a tab bar and maintains some transparency with the view beneath (an alternative approach to using a modal view)

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:myViewController.view];
```

However, when I add gesture recognisers to elements on `myViewController`, they give EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I interact with them.

If `myViewController` is instead launched as a modal view, it works fine, indicating that the problem is linked to it being a keyWindow subview.

Does anyone know a solution to this? Thanks.

Comment: Create a uiview subclass add gesture into that view and try to add an that view instead viewcontroller.view? and check is it working?

Comment: Jailani, that fixed it - switched from adding a ViewController to a UIView and it works

Comment: I didn't get you. How did you solve can you explain?

Comment: Ok you created a uiview and add it in uiwindow correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `UIView` subclass add gesture into that view and try to add an that view instead viewcontroller.view. You can add gesture recognizer to that `UIView`.